# KNOG BLINDER ARC 5.5 battery replacement

Tags: mountain-bike, road-bike, replacement, headlights, battery

Can anyone please tell me how I would go about changing the battery over in my light please!!! I have so far taken off the lens cover and have undone the 3 x 1.5mm Allen screws to release the outer housing but still can not get to the battery :-(  Thankyou

Comment: Have you read the user manual for this light? Is there a section on changing the battery? What about that section is unclear?

Comment: I have read the user manual and to my knowledge Paul there is nothing on changing the battery. Please correct me if I'm wrong!!

Comment: Do you a have link to the manual? It's difficult to verify your assessment without it.

Comment: https://www.knog.com.au/userguides

Comment: https://www.manualslib.com/manual/949228/Knog-Blinderarc-5-5.html

Comment: Additional information like that you should be edited into the question rather than included in the comments. Before we get too far down this road, do you have a fresh battery ready to go? It really appears this has an integrated battery

Comment: I do have a new 18650 battery ready to go and I'm sorry as this is the first time I've used this Forum

Comment: That light has an integrated battery and is not designed to be disassembled by the end user. A bit of googling indicated the battery is a fairly standard rechargable li-ion unit, so if you can get it apart the battery can be swapped out.

Comment: I understand that but it's the getting it apart without damaging it that I was hoping someone may have done it and run through it with me

Comment: @user43985 I don't own this light.  But you do, so please take photos showing how you did it, and create your own answer showing how you did it.

Comment: Is this bike light under warranty?  If so, simply return it for service or replacement, before getting inside it.

Comment: Well I did find the answer below when I originally looked so I followed that... That is untill I undid the Allen bolts... It did loosen the heat shield from the body but the circuit board is connected to some part in the body and I can not get the battery out.... :-(

Answer (score 6):

A quick google search turns up this forum entry by user “RNAV”:
https://www.bikeforums.net/electronics-lighting-gadgets/1085170-knog-arc-5-5-battery-replacement.html

> Remove the trim that surrounds the lens. There are four phillips
>   screws holding the lens in place -- Knog fills these in with epoxy so
>   you can't use them. I dug out the epoxy with a razor blade. Unscrew
>   and remove the lens, and you'll see the LED circuit board. There are
>   three black 1.5mm allen bolts; unscrew these. This loosens the heat
>   shield from the body of the light that holds the battery. Gently slide
>   the heat shield (with the circuit board still attached) forward, and
>   it will reveal the 18650 battery compartment (spring loaded on
>   negative end). Remove / replace battery, and perform steps in reverse
>   to reassemble.

As you can tell, it’s hard to get apart (not intended by the manufacturer) but at least it uses a standard 18650 Li-Ion battery.

Answer (score 3):

Hey bud thanks for the tutorial.  I had a big problem getting the heat body out enough. The ribbon cable popped off the led board. But at least it came off clean, and not off the button board!

I want to add real quickly that even though I haven’t replaced the battery yet, I have ascertained the original assembly procedure. The ribbon cable on the led ripped off and I will have to re-solder it.
The wire was really just a little too short to get the housing off.

Given that, once you do actually get the light apart and the battery out, you will see that the entire battery tray can be removed. It’s held in by two tabs that grip two notches in the case by the side pressure of the battery. Put it all together first, then firmly snap the entire assembly into the light housing. Prestochangeo!

Comment: Welcome to the site!  That's a good piece of firsthand info.   I've combined your comment into the answer.  You can also do this with [edit]   If you remember, it is helpful to snap photos too - each picture is literally worth a thousand words on SE.   Keep up the good work!